# jquery side bar menu issues onhover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a side menu bar just like we see in android phones using bootstrap and jQuery

What i want is that when i hover on a particular element of mine its inside sub-items should get displayed.

this is what i have done as of now

The code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Newspaper</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

    .mini-submenu{

  background:#000; 
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 9px;  
  /*position: relative;*/
  width: 42px;


}
.mini-submenu .icon-bar {
  border-radius: 1px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 22px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.mini-submenu .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}
</style>
<script>
var i=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myicon').click(function()
    {
        if(i==1)
        {

            $('.ic').hide(200);
            $('#mylist').animate({width:"90px"},300);
            $('.myicon').removeClass('fa-rotate-90');
            $('.myicon').addClass('fa-rotate-270');
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            $('.ic').show(200);
            $('#mylist').animate({width:"200px"},300);
            $('.myicon').removeClass('fa-rotate-270');
            $('.myicon').addClass('fa-rotate-90');
            i++;

        }
    });
 $('#mylist > a').hover(function(){

   $(this).children('div').show(1000); 



  },
  function(){



  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mylist">
<div class="mini-submenu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>

</a>
<div class="list-group col-md-3 collapse" id="mylist">
  <a class="list-group-item home" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo1"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i><span class="ic">&nbsp; Home</span><i class="fa fa-shield fa-rotate-90 myicon" style="float:right;margin-top:5px;"></i></a>
  <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo1" style="height: 0px;">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item ic">Submenu1.4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item ic">Submenu1.5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item ic">Submenu1.6</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i><span class="ic">&nbsp; Library</span></a>

  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i><span class="ic">&nbsp; Applications</span></a>
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw fa-spin"></i><span class="ic">&nbsp; Settings</span></a>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo" class="list-group-item">
  <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i><span class="ic">Submenu 1</span> 
          </a>
          <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo" style="height: 0px;">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item ic">Submenu1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item ic">Submenu1.2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="list-group-item ic">Submenu1.3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here's the example in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mGqhw)

Comment: can you provide JSFIDDLE link, so other can see and help with your problem

Comment: ohkk sure,give me a sec

Comment: here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/mGqhw/

Comment: in this what is want is that my submenu should come out to the left and onhover that should happen,currently i just dont understnd wat is happenin,and to be more precise i want that hover effect only when the icons are visible

Comment: by 'should come out to the left' does you mean that when the icon on the top left is hovered, the submenu will appear from the left? and did you want it to show only on hover and not on click like in your JSFIDDLE?

Comment: yes you are right,that's exactly what i want

Comment: last question, is it ok if the answer is done purely by CSS?

Comment: ya definitely,not a problem at all

Answer (score 0):

you can do that purely by CSS, here's how :

Wrap all of the element inside a container

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mylist">
        <!-- Button UI to hover -->
    </a>
    <div class="list-group">
        <!-- List Item that will slide -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then apply the CSS, for `list-group` which you want to be hidden and appear from left to right, use this

```
.list-group {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    right: 100%;    // this will make the element out of viewport in the left
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s; 
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

transition is used to make it slide, then add the CSS on hover and make the `list-group` appear

```
#container:hover .list-group {
    right: 0;
}
```

and also don't forget to add

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

so the container (div element) width not 100% of it's parent, but from it's content, so it wouldn't trigger the hover outside the button and `list-group`

here's the results on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mGqhw/3/)

Comment: that's really amazing,thank you so much,just one thing that's missing over here is that,when you click on that arrow icon the list-item should go inside and only display the icons and when i hover over the icons it should show the sub-menu's opening on the right,and click should be disabled,just check it over here http://mymenu.netne.net/html/